# Records for the last 7 days

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-analysis, analysis

Using Snowflake, I want to get the daily stock for the last 7 days.
Columns I have in this table are:  product_ID, date, and quantity

my desired out put should look like the following:

```
product_ID        DATE            Quantity 
82471             2022-07-14       40
82471             2022-07-15       35
82471             2022-07-16       34
82471             2022-07-17       50
82471             2022-07-18       53
82471             2022-07-19       51
82471             2022-07-20       40
```

Any ideas how to reach this output? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you need to aggregate your data, but based on your input, something like this may work:

```
select product_id, date, Quantity
from mytable
where "DATE" > dateadd( 'days', -7, current_date )
order by product_id, date DESC;
```